# Consulta AND, OR en MYQL

Tags: mysql-workbench

Qué tal, buenas tardes. 
Tengo una base de datos con 4 tablas que se relacionan linealmente. A las cuales ingreso datos que dependen de diferente precedente. 
Tengo el siguiente diagrama el cual lo ingreso a la base.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En él se puede ver que la letra "I" solo es para "E de J".
Sin embargo, en mi consulta me marca que "I" la tienen todas las demás actividades.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esté es el código que uso para realizar la consulta.

```
SELECT PAPA.idPAPA PAPA,HIJO.idHIJO HIJO,NIETO.idNIETO 
NIETO,BISNIETO.idBISNIETO BISNIETO
FROM PAPA,HIJO,NIETO,BISNIETO
WHERE HIJO.PreH=idPAPA
AND NIETO.PreN=HIJO.idHIJO 
AND (BISNIETO.PreB=NIETO.idNIETO OR NIETO.PreN=HIJO.idHIJO)
;
```

Quisiera saber de qué forma puedo excluir las "I" de las otras actividades en mi consulta. De la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quiza debieras usar join

Answer (score 1):

El problema es por la forma en como estas relacionando la consulta, lo ideal seria realizar la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT PAPA.idPAPA AS PAPA,HIJO.idHIJO AS HIJO,NIETO.idNIETO 
AS NIETO,BISNIETO.idBISNIETO AS BISNIETO
FROM PAPA 
LEFT JOIN HIJO ON HIJO.PreH=PAPA.idPAPA 
LEFT JOIN NIETO ON NIETO.PreN=HIJO.idHIJO 
LEFT JOIN BISNIETO ON BISNIETO.PreB=NIETO.idNIETO;
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, si la respuesta soluciona tu problema, no olvidez calificar.

Comment: Qué tal, muchas gracias por tu aporte, funciono correctamente :)

Comment: Pero sigo teniendo una duda,
En la tabla tengo dos actividades llamas "E", sin embargo, la "I" solo es para una de esas "E" y al momento de crear la tabla, me coloca las "I" en ambas "E".
¿Sabes por qué sucede ese?

Comment: hola @GaelRodriguez disculpa la demora, aun tienes ese inconveniente?

Comment: Qué tal, si de hecho en mi consulta el precedente de "I" sí es "E", sin embargo los precedentes de "E" son distintos, y en el diagrama de bloques que arriba mostre la "I" solo es de "E de J".

Comment: ¿Sabrás cómo restringir las letras de las cuales no depende mi última letra? 
Saludos.